# Can classical mechanics be derived from the standard model of particle physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, standard-model, approximations

Is there a way in which starting from the standard model, and performing a series of steps, classical mechanics can be derived? I'm curious if the equations of motion, whether Newtonian, Lagrangian or Hamiltonian, can be obtained using the Standard Model of particle physics. Ideally, it should be possible, since we know from experience that, in a human scale, classical mechanics provides extremely accurate results and it is a useful theory, and also that the Standard Model is able to explain everything except for gravity.

Comment: Yes definitely classical mechanics can be derived from particle physics or quantum mechanics. See [Correspondence principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_principle#:~:text=In%20physics%2C%20the%20correspondence%20principle,limit%20of%20large%20quantum%20numbers.)

Comment: Starting from the standard model is possible overkill... The standard classical limit is usually taken from plain NR QM to CM in the limit of small ℏ. Throwing absolutely every pot on the fire makes every problem intractable, albeit solvable, in principle, as per agreement in the community.... But problems are solved in confined ambits first.

Comment: Yes oviously!   